# HTML - Set background image

Tags: html, css

i have two folders

1: WebContent/WEB-INF/resources/css/style.css

2: WebContent/WEB-INF/resources/img/biggerdot.png

i want to take a background image with this code

```
background: url('../img/biggerdot.png') center bottom no-repeat;
```

But nothing happens.

**Also tried:**

```
background: url('/img/biggerdot.png') center bottom no-repeat;
background: url('../../img/biggerdot.png') center bottom no-repeat;
```

THX for help

Answer (score 0):

Try Out This

```
background: url('../img/biggerdot.png') center bottom no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
background: url('img/biggerdot.png') center bottom no-repeat;
```